# Mail server constantly tries to send email

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I have a mail server with Postfix and Dovecot installed and I've noticed it endlessly tries to send out malformed emails with misspelled address. For example if I type `to: anton@outlok.com` (misspelled `outlook.com`) it will keep trying to send this letter with 30-40 minute intervals getting "connection timed out" every time. How do I disable this behavior and limit the number of attempts?

Comment: `man postconf` will tell you which config files you can use to affect the behaviour of Postfix.

Comment: If the domain you typed has an A record out there, that's enough for it to try until its internal timeout is reached. Have a look at this, if you're interested in how it decides that: http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#hammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change how long messages stay in the postfix queue before being dropped by setting

> maximal_queue_lifetime = Xd

in /etc/postfix/main.cf

You might want to check also minimal_backoff_time and maximal_backoff_time which are the minimum and maximal amount of time a message won't be looked at after a delivery failure.

For other values that might be of use to you check the documentation of postfix, there are plenty...